# leaflet-routing-machine OSRM too many requests with status code 429

Tags: angular, osrm, leaflet-routing-machine

I have used leaflet-routing-machine with OSRM in it. But server returns too many requests with status code 429 when executing following code

```
L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
            L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
        ]
    }).addTo(map);
```

the OSRM service url is https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/11.94,57.74;11.949,57.6792?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true&hints=;

How else can i achieve this?

Comment: any help appreciated :)

Comment: Any one help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The demo server [documentation](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Demo-server) states:

> The demoserver will have a service-wide rate limit of 5000 req/minute. Looking at past logs, it stays below this about 98% of the time, but be prepared for HTTP 429 responses, and be aware that heavy usage may cause rate limiting for everyone else if you flood the server.

Comment: So using OSRM is not a best way to go right? have to go for another option. Thanks for you reply by the way.

Comment: By the way it fails even after  3 4 request attempts within a minute

Comment: OSRM is great, but a demo is a demo. If you need reliability you'll either have to host it by yourself or pay for the service provided.

Comment: How do you undo getting locked out?

Comment: Dear a query: how do you pay?

Comment: @Suful have you found a solution ?